# Expo SDK45.04 upgrade - fontFamily "FontAwesome" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Suddenly all the icons of my app are not loading.

I' m using "@expo/vector-icons"

and importing icons in the following way:

```
import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";
//or
import Ionicons from "@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons";
```

This is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.1.1",
    "@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "@use-expo/font": "^2.0.0",
    "expo": "^45.0.4",
    "expo-app-loading": "~1.3.0",
}
```

I' ve tried:

- deleting node_modules, yarn.lock, expo dir
- reinstalling all with ----> yarn install
- running project and clearing cache --> expo r -c

Also tried to load fonts async

```
function cacheFonts(fonts) {
  return fonts.map((font) => Font.loadAsync(font));
}

export default function App() {
  const [fontLoaded, setfontLoaded] = useState(false);
  const loadAssetsAsync = async () => {
    const fontAssets = cacheFonts([FontAwesome.font]);
    await Promise.all([...fontAssets]);
  }; 

  if (!fontLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={loadAssetsAsync}
        onFinish={() => setfontLoaded(true)}
        onError={console.warn}
      >
        <LoadingScreen></LoadingScreen>
      </AppLoading>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution to this? I just upgraded to expo45 and losing my mind over this problem

Comment: No I'm sorry, i've changed all my icons to images

Comment: It was very weird, i rolledback the upgrade and then went straight to v46 and didn't have this problem.